# fetch() method is throwing error while using in component in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I am using `fetch()` method in the navigation component but when I am running my app I am seeing `[Vue warn]: Property or method "menus" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`.

**My Script code in navigation.**

```
export default {
  name: 'AppHeader',
  methods: {
    async fetch ({ $content }) {
      const menus = await $content('menu').fetch()
      return {
        menus
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I have tried to add menus array in data but no luck.**

```
export default {
  name: 'AppHeader',
  data () {
    return {
      menus: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetch ({ $content }) {
      const menus = await $content('menu').fetch()
      return {
        menus
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using fetch as if it were asyncData which is not. Fetch has access to this, so you should to something like this.menus = await $content('menu').fetch(). Take a look at [fetch hook](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/features/data-fetching/)

Comment: @drocha87 Using `this.menus = await $content('menu').fetch()` solves error problem but I am getting empty array. 
I have attached the SS.
https://pasteboard.co/Jv0gDxd.png

`export default {
  name: 'AppHeader',
  async fetch ({ $content }) {
    this.menus = await $content('menu').fetch()
  },
  data () {
    return {
      menus: []
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Now I realized that you are using fetch inside methods, and probably you never call that method. You should take away fetch from methods. So again fetch should be out of methods object. Pay attention here [content](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/features/data-fetching/)